# Split zip into smaller zip files

Tags: zip

I need weekly to upload bunch of pdf file to grading platform, in the form of zip, but the website has limit of 250Mb per zip file, and it takes me too much time to split the zip I have into smaller zip files.

What is the simplest way to split a zip into chunks with max size?

A way that would work on other unix-like platform (like my mac at work) will be grate.

I'm looking an existing command that will do it, or some simple python (or node, or any other simple to use languages) module that will help we write a small script that does it.

Comment: I think this might be useful https://superuser.com/questions/336219/how-do-i-split-a-zip-file-into-multiple-segments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`zipsplit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/zipsplit.1.html) which is part of the `zip` package:

```
zipsplit -n $(( 250 * 1024 * 1024 )) your_zipfile.zip
```

It splits an existing zipfile into smaller chunks. The size of each
chunk can be supplied via the `-n` switch. It defaults to
360000 because years ago floppy disks had a capacity of 360 kB.

Another option would be to create the chunks in the first place while
zipping (see [`zip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/zip.1.html), especially the `-s` switch) and thus avoiding
the separate `zipsplit` step:

```
zip -s 250m new-zipfile file1 file2 file3...
```

Unfortunately `unzip new-zipfile.zip` cannot handle the chunks created
via `zip -s` so you have to join them on the target side before unzipping:

```
zip --fix new-zipfile --out joined-zipfile
unzip joined-zipfile
```

Comment: the files created will be real zip file of chunks (means that later on I will need to put them together) of the original one? If my original file contains f1.pdf (25MB) ,f2.pdf (20MB) and f3.pdf (8MB)  and the limit is 50MB per zip file I want the output to be two zip files, one with f1.pdf and f2.pdf and one with f3.pdf.

Comment: @BarakOhana `zipsplit` will create a number of stand-alone zipfiles each of which can be unzipped on its own (no joining needed). `zip -s` on the other hand creates a number of files that must be joined via `zip --fix` because `unzip` cannot currently handle these files. I'd go with `zipsplit` in your case.

Comment: As a note, this method doesn't work if archive contains a file that is larger than desired chunk size

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of independent extraction. I'm trying to handle my large zip files from exporting videos from iCloud.

Comment: Great answer - helped explain the units used in the `-n` argument